# Bitwise operator x >> 1 and x >> 0

Tags: javascript, numbers, operators, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What do these operators do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-operators-do)
>   [>> in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437169/in-javascript)

Can somebody please explain the bitwise operator `>> 1`?

example:

`65 >> 1 = 32`

and also when `>> 0`

what does it achieve in this example:

`var size = (Math.random() * 100 >> 0) + 20;`

Comment: 65 = `1000001`, shifting bits will give you `0100000`, which represents `32`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do these operators do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-operators-do), [>> in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437169/in-javascript) and [Meaning of >>, <<, | and & in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541455/meaning-of-and-in-javascript). http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+bitwise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var size = (Math.random() * 100 >> 0) + 20;
```

`>> 0` in the above example is used to eliminate the fractional portion, as follows:

1. Math.random() returns a number between 0 and 0.99999999...
2. This number multiplied by 100 gives you another number between 0 and 99.999999...
3. This number is right shifted 0 times. The number is implicitly cast to an integer for the shift operation; right shifting 0 times does not have any effect on the value of the resulting integer. You thus end up with an integer between 0 and 99. Note that you could have used the `Math.floor()` function instead of `>> 0`.
4. Add 20 to the integer, the result is an integer between 20 and 119.

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise operator **>>** means shift right.
It moves the binary value to the right (and removes the right-most bit).

**65 >> 1** in binary is:

**1000001 >> 1 = 100000 = 32**

It effectively divides  the number into 2 and drops the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

The operator '>>' shifts the contents of a variable right by 1 bit. This results, effectively, in **integer** division of that value by 2 as you show in your example:

```
   65 >> 1 = 32
```

Let's say that a variable is always 32 bits long. The example then says:

```
   65 decimal >> 1 = 32  or, in hex, 0x000041 >> 1 = 0x00000020
```

More generally: the operator '>>' divides its operand, as a 32-bit integer, by the power of 2 whose value is the shift length. Thus:

```
  129 decimal >> 1 = 64  or  0x000081 >> 1 = 0x000040
  129 decimal >> 2 = 32  or  0x000081 >> 2 = 0x000020
  129 decimal >> 5 =  2  or  0x000081 >> 5 = 0x000002
```

and

```
  129 decimal >> 8 =  0  or: 0x000081 >> 8 = 0x000000
```

The operator '<<' ***multiplies*** its operand, as you'd expect.

I don't know how Math.random( ) operates, but I'm willing to bet that the shift of its floating-point returned value right by 0 turns that number into an  integer, because shifting left and right has arithmetic meaning only when the operand is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise shift operator shifts each bit of the input x bits to the right (>>) or to the left (<<).

65 is 1000001, thus 65 >> 1 = 0100000, which is 32.

**EDIT**

Here are some useful links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

http://javascript.about.com/library/blbitop.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftLeft.htm

Answer (score 0):

`>> X` takes the binary number and moves all the digits right by `X` places.

In your example, you use 65, which is 01000001 in binary.  If you shift that right by one, the first space (on the left) gets filled in with a 0, and the last digit 'falls off the end'.  Giving 00100000, which is the binary representation for 32.

`>> 0`, therefore shifts the number 0 spaces to the right, and does nothing.

'<< X', does the same, but shifts the number to the left.

These can be compared to multiplying by 2^X (Left-shift) or divinding by 2^X (right-shift), but it should be noted that a binary shift is much faster than a division operation.

Comment: *">> 0, therefore shifts the number 0 spaces to the right, and does nothing."* - not true.  In JavaScript it converts the number to a 32 bit integer.  On a number that is already a 32 bit integer it appears to do nothing, but on a larger number or a floating point number it will reduce/floor accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand why the output is 32 from rsplak's post. `>>` is the Right Bit Shift operator and using it as `>> 1` will cause every bit to be shifted one place to the right. This means, if the rightmost bit was **1**, it would get expelled and the left most bit will contain **0**.

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise operator shifts an expression by a number of digits. So in your example you have
65 which ist binary 0100 0001 shiftet 1 position to the right so you got 0010 0000 which is 32 decimal.

Another example:
48 >> 3 = 6

48 decimal is 0011 0000 binary shifted 3 to the right is 0000 0110 which is 6 decimal.

For your second example I can not help you - I can not image why I would shift an expression by 0 positions but maybe you can find out debugging it?